# multiple arrays object manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
array1 = [{"name":"John"},{"name":"James"}];
array2 = [{"gred_id":1,"name":"John","gred":"A"},{"gred_id":2,"name":"James","gred":"B"}];
```

I have 2 array like above. By comparing the **name of the candidate**, I want to put gred_id into array1. I stuck here

```
$.each(array1,function(){
    var name= this["name"];

    $.each(array2, function(){
        if(name == this.name){
            this["grey_id"] = {"grey_id":this.id}; // not sure this is correct or wrong
        }
    });
});
```

This is what I want in the end :

```
array1 = [{"name":"John","gred_id":1},{"name":"James","gred_id":2}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per jQuery's `.each()` [documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), you do not need to store the item in a variable. You can use `.each()` function parameters. The first parameter returns the index, the second parameter returns the item.

Thus, you can optimize the code like so.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvhkov2a/)

```
var array1 = [{"name":"John"},{"name":"James"}];
var array2 = [{"gred_id":1,"name":"John","gred":"A"},{"gred_id":2,"name":"James","gred":"B"}];

$.each(array1, function (i, item) {
    $.each(array2, function (j, val) {
        if (item.name === val.name) {
            item.grey_id = val.gred_id;     
        }
    });
});
```

Output

```
array1 = [{"name":"John","gred_id":1},{"name":"James","gred_id":2}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object1 iteration as an child object, since this gets modified when there is a different scope. `itm1=this` so the array1 objects will be stored in each iteration in scope array1 iteration and array2 iteration

```
var array1 = [{"name":"John"},{"name":"James"}];
var array2 = [{"gred_id":1,"name":"John","gred":"A"},{"gred_id":2,"name":"James","gred":"B"}];
var itm1;
$.each(array1,function(){
    itm1= this;
    $.each(array2, function(){
        if(itm1.name == this.name){
            itm1.grey_id = this.gred_id; // here this refers to array2 iteration
        }
    });
});

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `$.map()`

```js
var array1 = [{
  "name": "John"
}, {
  "name": "James"
}];

var array2 = [{
  "gred_id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "gred": "A"
}, {
  "gred_id": 2,
  "name": "James",
  "gred": "B"
}];

array1 = $.map(array1, function(val, key) {
  return val.name === array2[key].name 
         ? $.extend({}, val, {"gred_id": array2[key].gred_id}) 
         : val
});

$("pre").text(JSON.stringify(array1, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, `$.grep` with `$.each`,

```
$.each(array1, function(key, val){
    match = $.grep(array2, function(obj){   // search for match
        return obj.name == val.name;
    });
    array1[key].gred_id = match[0].gred_id; // assign the match
});
```